# Django bulk_create() with inexistent ForeignKey

Tags: django, bulk-create

I have 2 models. For simplicity, I deleted all unnecessary fields.

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=36, primary_key=True, null=False)
    age = models.IntegerFiels(default=-1)
```

and

```
class Device(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Through the API, I receive information about devices and create a list with devices.

```
devices = []
for device_data in data:
    devices.append(
        Device(
            user_id=device_data("user_id")
        )
    )
```

Once I have the list of devices, I add it to the database.

```
Device.objects.bulk_create(devices, ignore_conflicts=True)
```

The problem is that if, when creating a Device, I specified a user_id that is not in the database, I will get a crash because I am trying to link with a non-existent id.

Now to get around this I do the following:

```
devices = []
users = []
for device_data in data:
    users.append(
        User(
            id=device_data("user_id", age = -1)
        )
    )
    devices.append(
        Device(
            user_id=device_data("user_id")
        )
    )
```

Then, when saving:

```
User.objects.bulk_create(users, ignore_conflicts=True)
Device.objects.bulk_create(devices, ignore_conflicts=True)
User.objects.filter(age=-1).delete()
```

How can I make sure that when saving, if the specified user_id does not exist, this device is not added?

**UPDATED:**

Another solution is to change the field

```
User.age = models.IntegerFiels(null=True)
```

and

```
 Device.user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

After this, I can save devices without users.

```
Device.objects.bulk_create(devices, ignore_conflicts=True)
```

After which, do:
Device.objects.filter(user__age__isnull=True).delete()

This works, but I don’t like the fact that you need to check for age, and not for the user itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that if, when creating a Device, I specified a user_id that is not in the database, I will get a crash because I am trying to link with a non-existent id.

If you don't want your devices to require a User, then make the ForeignKey [nullable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#null):

```py
class Device(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=true)
```

**UPDATE**
Oh I misunderstood. You want to bulk create only those Devices that have an existing user id? Why not just filter out the device data with usable user_id?

```py
devices = []
user_ids = User.objects.values_list("id", flat=True)
# assuming that device_data is a dictionary
for device_data in data:
    if "user_id" in device_data and device_data["user_id"] in user_ids:
        devices.append(Device(**device_data))
```

Comment: I changed the "user" field this way: models.ForeignKey( User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True) Now, my code doesn't crash, the devices are saved, but if I try to print (device.user), I get the error main.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.

Please read the "update" of the post.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your question. Please , see the update to my post.

Comment: Of course, it will work, but how economical is it if the user base is several tens of millions? In this case, I will have to store a huge dictionary in memory, and this despite the fact that situations when device_data["user_id"] will not be in the database are very rare.

Comment: Therefore, I was looking for a solution on how to force bulk_create not to save such devices, or if this is not possible, then at least, when deleting such records, look for something like filter(user__isnull=True), and not filter(user__age__isnull=True) ( more on that in the update).

Comment: Unless you do this operation repeatedly, I wouldn't worry too much about memory size or time constraints. The query for ids is cheap and fast, and a list of ten million numbers isn't that big either (you can check the size yourself: `import sys; sys.getsizeof(user_ids)` shows it in bytes). Do it in the most straight-forward way; only create objects for devices that have an existing user. Don't overthink it. **If your database schema does not allow devices without users, then you should not change your schema just to get this operation to pass.**

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions for you

1 - apply a query to check if user is exists or not

```
devices = []
for device_data in data:
user_id = device_data.get("user_id")  # Use get() to avoid KeyError if user_id is not present
if User.objects.filter(id=user_id).exists():
    device = Device(user_id=user_id)
    devices.append(device)
```

**and that will be expensive operation if you have a big data**

2 - apply Try Catch block with non bulk operation with simple for loop, and you can use a background task to improve it if that meet system requirements

3 - apply filter when you are getting data from API if you can to get only common values

4 - make user in Device model accept Null value and make it as a default value if there is no data and in this way you can keep all data if you need it in feature to analysis it and you can control how you will get it using filter

Comment: 1) is too expensive
2) i can't use
3) A little better, I no longer have to add users to the database, but I still have to make additional queries in the database.
4) I changed the "user" field this way:
models.ForeignKey(
         User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None
     )

Now, my code doesn't crash, the devices are saved, but if I try to print (device.user), I get the error main.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.

Comment: And I can’t write a filter checking Device.user for None, because there is a connection, but with a non-existent object.

Comment: If I write "print(device.user__id)", I don't get a crash like I do with "print(device.user)". I get my saved ID.

Comment: I've updated the post. Please read it, maybe you have an idea.